# Можно ли так сказать?

Tags: нормы-языка

пешая экскурсия

Answer (score 2):

Да, конечно. Ведь экскурсия, к примеру, по городу может быть как пешей, так и на автобусе.
Мы ездили на экскурсию. Мы ходили на экскурсию, либо принимали участие в пешей экскурсии.

Answer (score 1):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ

ПЕШЕХОДНЫЙ, 1.Предназначенный для ходьбы пешком. П. переход. П-ое движение. П. мостик.
2.Совершаемый пешком. П-ые прогулки. П-ые туристические маршруты.

ПЕШИЙ, -ая, -ее.
1.Идущий пешком. П. отряд. П-ие путешественники.
2.Совершаемый пешком; связанный с передвижением пешком. П. переход. П. путь. П-ая прогулка.

Слова "пеший и пешеходный" различаются по первым значениям, но сходны по вторым. В сочетании со словом "прогулка" используются оба слова, но сочетание "пешеходная экскурсия" более употребительно и, возможно, относится к нейтральному стилю речи. Пешая экскурсия - это,скорее, разговорный вариант.

Comment: Как вы верно заметили, София, пешеходный - предназначенный для ходьбы пешком, коими могут быть дорожки,тропы, мосты, переходы, т.е. этим словом определяется предназначение места.  Прогулки же и экскурсии - это скорее действия, совершаемые определёнными способами: пешим, конным, на транспорте... Потому, исходя из ваших же рассуждений, я предпочёл бы пешую экскурсию, пешеходной.

Comment: Значение "совершаемый пешком" - это ВТОРОЕ значение у ОБОИХ слов, так что приходится выбирать. В Интернете чаще можно встретить пешеходную экскурсию и пешую прогулку. Возможно, это объясняется следующим образом.  Прогулка пешком и пешая прогулка - оба выражения встречаются одинаково часто и характерны для разговорной речи или художественного стиля. Пешеходная экскурсия -  это, скорее, термин, предназначенный  для туристических агентств.

Comment: Думаю, туристические агентства экскурсии считают пешеходными по той простой причине, что они ближе к изучению содержимого кошелька своего клиента, чем к семантике слова.